# When using Group By in PowerBI desktop Column value is not active

Tags: sql-server, powerbi, dax

In my data set, each `PolicyNumber` can have multiple `ClaimNumber`. So all I want to do is to get Unique `PolicyNumber` and Count the number of Claims (`ClaimNumber`) for each `PolicyNumber`. (Like a pivot table in Excel)

In Power BI I click `Edit Query`, click `Group By`, specifying the column I want to group on which is `PolicyNumber`, giving the name to new column (`CountOfClaims`), Operation - `Count Rows`...but I am unable to choose `Column` value. For some reason its inactive. It works if I need to `Sum`, but I simply need to count `ClaimNumber` for each `PolicyNumber`
It should be so simple. 
What am I missing here?

[image]

This is what I am trying to achieve:

[image]

Also when I am choosing Group By on a panel, then the query has Exclamation sign. I couldnt find a meaning of it.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When counting rows it does not matter which column you count against, which is why Power BI doesn't populate the drop down.

The Group By dialog does not support distinct column counts (as for April 2017).

Instead, you can add a measure to your data model, using [DAX](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ee634396.aspx), that returns a [distinct count](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492142.aspx).

```
=DISTINCTCOUNT([ClaimNumber])
```

Or you can create a 2nd table, that sits on top of the first, which contains only unique combinations of `PolicyNumber` and `ClaimNumber`.  You could then group by `PolicyNumber` and count the rows, which would return the distinct claim count.

Comment: Thanks. My final goal is to massage this query to get unique `PolicyNumber`, `Counts`, and `SUM(Losses)` so then I can join this query to another dataset, that also has `PolicyNumber`

Comment: One of the features I really like in Power BI, is the ability to organise the queries into folders.  I often need to build tables on tables, which can become rather confusing.  To make things clearer I normally place the *base* queries in a folder called stage.  I then build dimension and fact *tables* on top of these objects, again in separate folders.  As a general rule, I like to stick to 2/3 layers.  After that, I can't understand my own projects.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if there is a way to get somewhere completed PBI reports, just to see the logic, functions, measures etc. Just in order to learn it faster. 
Thanks

Comment: The excellent [Power Pivot Pro](https://powerpivotpro.com/) has lots of tutorials and many detailed blog posts.  There are also a number of sample projects on the [Power BI website](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-sample-datasets/).